# Calculate previous SUM value

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have 2 **SQL Server 2005** tables: `Names` and `Scores`

Names table:

```
  NameID, Name,   Age
  1,      'John', 23
  2,      'Ryan', 20
```

Scores table:

```
  ScoreID, NameID, ScoreDate,  ScoreValue
  1,       1,      01/01/2011, 250
  2,       1,      02/01/2011, 300
  3,       1,      03/01/2011, 100
  4,       2,      01/01/2011, 150
  5,       2,      02/01/2011, 350
  6,       2,      03/01/2011, 200
```

I want to get for a given month:

`Name, Age, current ScoreValue, sum(ScoreValue) for previous months`

Something like this form the month of `february`:

```
John, 23, 300, 550
Ryan, 20, 350, 500
```

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on - the join, the aggregation, finding the latest, filtering on a month? I also don't see where you're getting the totals from - you've only got one record for each player for Feb?

Comment: I want to get the total for all the previous values (from all the previous dates including the current month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you want:

```
select n.Name,
       s1.ScoreId, 
       s1.nameId, 
       s1.ScoreValue,
       sum(s2.ScoreValue) Prevmonths
from   names n
       inner join scores s1 on n.NameId = s1.NameId
       left  join scores s2 -- make left join in case no previous month
         on  s1.NameId = s2.NameId 
         and s1.ScoreDate >= s2.ScoreDate -- >= means include current onth
group by n.Name,
       s1.ScoreId, 
       s1.nameId, 
       s1.ScoreValue
```

GJ

Comment: Thank you! I've used part of your script.